# Endnote style within latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I used EndNote to export references by using this Style Orient Pharm Exp Med.ens
I have exported to make it lib.bib in order to use it in latex.

[image]

in Latex, I use the following to define library:

```
\bibliographystyle{??}
\bibliography{lib}
```

I don't know how to use the style of Endnote with latex, because, in citation latex can't know which ref o use.

```
\citep{(Wang 2013)}
```

it must be the first author name and the year. but it didn't work cause it can't see the style

> > exported lib:

```
Wang X (2013) Intelligent multi-camera video surveillance: A review Pattern   recognition letters 34:3-19
Zhu J, Lao Y, Zheng YF (2010) Object tracking in structured environments for video surveillance applications Circuits and Systems for Video Technology, IEEE Transactions on 20:223-235
```

Comment: In your [former question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292680/refb-refj-in-latex) (which is not resolved yet) you are submitting to Springer. They define the style of the bibliography.

Comment: You have to export to bibtex (or something  like that, i don't know endnote), not to plain text.

Comment: The Bibtex key doesn't need to be author year - it just needs to be a unique label. Author year became a convention because it's human readable too.

Answer (score 2):

Install [JabRef](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/releases/tag/v3.2) on your system. Then import the exported file from EndNote into JabRef and choose the option "create bibkeys". Then JabRef creates a key, build by name and year, for each entry.

This way is a bit easier than to modify the EndNote export.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of steps. **Step 1**. Before you export from EndNote, each reference needs to be labeled so that it can be identified by a cite command in LaTeX.  You can do this manually, say, by using the author surname and year (e.g. jones16). Put the label in EndNotes's label field.  If you have many references to label you can use this tool: https://github.com/JonnoFTW/BibTeX-Label-Creator. It is an EndNote plugin that can be used to automatically label all the references you want to export. **Step 2**. You then need to export from EndNote in Bibtex format, as indicated by @Johannes_B. You can get the right export filter from here:  http://www.rhizobia.co.nz/latex/convert. There is a good discussion of how to use it. Save the exported file with a bib extension so that LaTeX can find it. Be patient. Like most things in Latex, the process is easy once it is familiar.