# how to customise bib refrence?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using EndNote

I want to customise refrences in the bib file.

currently bib file has this

```
@article{RN1,
   author = {Baškarada, Saša and Koronios, Andy},
   title = {Unicorn data scientist: the rarest of breeds},
   journal = {Program},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

and can be used with reference RN1

I want to change that to my own refenece number

something like "Tx847"

I tried using Label

but it does not work

I want to use in my Tex

> Here is my reference~\cite{Tx847}

anyother way to do that?

***Update***

I edited style citation template to use Label

[image]

But the bib file still showing the orginal citation tag and does not show any label

[image]

Comment: Is there a problem with just changing the `RN1` in the bib file to `Tx847`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, There are hundreds of references and the label is not showing in the bib file, therefore I dont know what is my reference tag is goiing to be.. unless I go search in all references and open the tagging file and compare each reference one by one. which is going to take days and not error free.. so I thought it would be much easier if I can just cite using the label..

Comment: No idea of EndNote, but if you have a huge .bib file you can use JabRef to bulk rename the bibkeys according to a  pattern, although I would not use any pattern except the default (`[auth][year]`) that will produce keys as `Alaa2018`, by far more useful in practice than `RN1` or `Tx847` or some other  code unrelated with the reference fields.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538510/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292682/35864. By default EndNote exports its `.bib` entries with this frankly pointless `RN...` label. You'll have to manually work around this by using a custom exporter.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, you will need to define the conversion from what is in the bib file to the labels you want to use instead.  For that I have provided `\symblabel{<old>}{<new>}`.  Then, in the document, you can use `\symbcite{<new>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\newcommand\symblabel[2]{\expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand\symbcite[1]{\cite{\csname #1\endcsname}}
\begin{filecontents*}{junk.bib}
@article{RN1,
   author = {Baškarada, Saša and Koronios, Andy},
   title = {Unicorn data scientist: the rarest of breeds},
   journal = {Program},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\symblabel{RN1}{Tx847}

In \symbcite{Tx847} blah, blah blah

\ldots

Baškarada et al also show\symbcite{Tx847}

\bibliography{junk}

\end{document}
```

[image]